# Visa4UK Appointments Pakistan

Tags: visas, online-resources, pakistan, biometric-passports

Just wondered if anyone else is trying to apply for a settlement (spouse) visa for their respective partners to come to the UK. I have completed the application and confirmed as such. I then go to the biometrics page and confirm that and following that there are no appointments in Pakistan for any of the options ( Standard / Premium) etc at any location.

Does anyone know why this is? Could it be to do with Ramadan?